# php mysql_query inside javascript confirmation

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, confirmation

I have a PHP file which is called by a form, and the javascript code inside is not working properly.

```
<?php
  $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
  if($var1==1){
  ?>
    <script>
    if(confirmation('Some text')){ 
    <?                 
      mysql_query('update table set ...'); 
    ?>             
    }else{
      alert('error');
    }
    </script> 
  <?
  }
?>
```

What happens is that even when I hit Cancel on the confirmation window, the mysql query is executed.
The if($var==1) instruction is just as demonstration. I have several ifs and mysql instructions before the javascript code.

Comment: This is awful spaghetti code. If you have a problem with the Javascript code, you have to look at the end result that your PHP generates. Start with your browser's error console. (Also consider not dynamically generating JS. It's rarely needed and always confusing.)

Comment: PHP is run on the server; JavaScript on the client. What's happening is that the mysql_query is being run when the page is generated - it doesn't matter what button you press on the page.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a `server-side` language, it gets executed before the `client-side` Javascript get executed. Hence, it processes the condition check, only after the PHP script is run. You need to use `AJAX` for such purposes.